# Can't see output, only in terminal

Tags: python, go, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write some Go code in VScode.

I have the Code Runner (v. 0.9.9) and Go (v 0.10.2) extensions.

I tried to run the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")

}
```

In the `output` tab I got:

```
[Running] go run "/home/joe/code/test.go"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.236 seconds
```

Which does not include the output of the Println statement. While if I run it from terminal (from VScode even), I get:

```
joe@HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~/code$ go run test.go
Hello, World!
```

This, by the way, repeats itself with other languages I've tried as well (like Python).

How can I fix this so I can get the actual output to the output tab?

Comment: When you try this with Python, what's your code and its output?

Comment: can you reference the extension you are referring?

Answer (score 0):

For `output` tab only execute `go test` without verbose command. you must be add `-v` argument to `go test` config.

Add this to settings.json on VSCODE

```
"go.testFlags": ["-v"],
```

Comment: But, what's wrong with running `go run`? is his `output` is being treated as `stderr` pipe? also, it is happening for all language, not only go!